# English language

Tags: babel, languages, spelling

I really don't understand why `LaTeX` still doesn't recognize English language when I write and in this way it doesn't check spelling or grammar mistakes. I've installed the `babel` package using English but it doesn't make any difference, it is always trying to work with Italian, my language. Any suggestion? I'm driving crazy.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! LaTeX does no human language check, neither grammar nor spelling ;-)

Comment: Spell-checking is done by your editor but certainly not by LaTeX…

Comment: Which editor are you using?  As mentioned, the LaTeX compilation process does no checking of spelling or grammar, but you likely have some built-in functionality to whatever editor you are using.  This functionality probably refers to the system-wide language which you possibly have set to italian?  For example, in TexShop preferences under the editor section there is a check spelling option.

Comment: The `babel` package ensures appropriate hyphenation patterns are used and that standard headings etc. are in the desired language.  Other tools should be used for spell checking etc. These are usually system dependent.  One might imagine `luatex` could interact with them though I don't believe such an interface currently exists.

Comment: Instead of "english" try "USenglish" (or "UKenglish") for babel. That will help with hyphenation (but not check spelling or grammar).

Answer (score 4):

`LaTeX` does not perform any spell - checking itself, but the used editor can do so.

Grammar rules, regardless which human language, are not topic of LaTeX (and most likely even not addressed by any editor at all), unless they are being dealt by linguists that use LaTeX for typesetting, but this does not matter here.

Hyphenation is governed by spelling and pronounciation rules, this is provided by `TeX` however (as long as the hyphenation patterns are correct!) and there packages for that as well, such as `babel` and `polyglossia` dealing with such language issues, amongst country specific typography.

Comment: Since you dislike having your posts edited: second paragraph should end `).` rather than `.`. Maybe 'are not a matter for LaTeX' or 'are not the concern of LaTeX'? In the final paragraph, why not just, 'TeX does include hyphenation patterns and so LaTeX will hyphenate text according to the patterns for the relevant language, provided that the patterns for that language are loaded.' I don't really know what you mean about them being 'between spelling and language rules', but probably it makes better sense in German ;).

Comment: I should have written `spelling and pronounciation rules` rather